# Chess results to leader board

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table containing results of chess matches:

| id | player_white | player_black | result | session_start | session_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jonathan1 | TrentX | 0 | 2020-01-01 13:10:10 | 2020-01-01 13:15:23 |
| 2 | TrentX | Jonathan1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 13:18:32 | 2020-01-01 13:23:13 |
| 3 | Ezekiel2001 | Jonathan1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 13:30:12 | 2020-01-01 13:37:01 |
| 4 | Ezekiel2001 | TrentX | 3 | 2020-01-01 13:40:08 | 2020-01-01 13:44:02 |
| 5 | Jonathan1 | Ezekiel2001 | 4 | 2020-01-01 13:48:32 | 2020-01-01 13:53:56 |
| 6 | TrentX | Ezekiel2001 | 1 | 2020-01-01 13:56:30 | 2020-01-01 13:59:02 |

`result` is an enum where:

- 0 = white victory
- 1 = black victory
- 2 = draw by agreement
- 3 = draw by stalemate
- 4 = draw by repetition
- 5 = draw by fifty move rule
- 6 = aborted

I would like to sort players by maximum number of victories and draws to display a leader board. Is there any straightforward way to get this leader board view or are any changes required in the way the data is organized?

Comment: Are victories and draws really weighted equally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the white and black victories along with draws and then apply group by on counts to get the result set.
Please refer below.

```
SELECT player, count(1) number_of_victories_and_draws
FROM(
SELECT player_white player, result from plays pw_victory_draw_table where result IN( 0, 2, 3, 4, 5)
UNION ALL
SELECT player_black player, result  from plays pb_victory_draw_table where result IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
) playes_union_table
GROUP BY player
ORDER BY 1;
```

Result:

```
Ezekiel2001 3
Jonathan1   4
TrentX  1
```

Answer (score 0):

> "*… changes required in the way the data is organized?*"

Lacking normalization every condition requires sub-query :

```
SELECT
                        player_name,
    sum(player_wins) AS player_wins,
    sum(player_loss) AS player_loss,
    sum(player_draw) AS player_draw
FROM (

    SELECT
        player_white AS player_name,
        count(*)     AS player_wins,
        0            AS player_loss,
        0            AS player_draw
    FROM
        tablename
    WHERE
        result = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        player_black AS player_name,
        count(*)     AS player_wins,
        0            AS player_loss,
        0            AS player_draw
    FROM
        tablename
    WHERE
        result = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        player_white AS player_name,
        0            AS player_wins,
        count(*)     AS player_loss,
        0            AS player_draw
    FROM
        tablename
    WHERE
        result = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        player_black AS player_name,
        0            AS player_wins,
        count(*)     AS player_loss,
        0            AS player_draw
    FROM
        tablename
    WHERE
        result = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        player_white AS player_name,
        0            AS player_wins,
        0            AS player_loss,
        count(*)     AS player_draw
    FROM
        table_name
    WHERE
        result BETWEEN 2 AND 5

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        player_black AS player_name,
        0            AS player_wins,
        0            AS player_loss,
        count(*)     AS player_draw
    FROM
        table_name
    WHERE
        result BETWEEN 2 AND 5

)
GROUP BY
    player_name
ORDER BY
    player_wins DESC,
    player_loss  ASC,
    player_draw DESC,
    player_name  ASC
;
```